# UIPickerView disable column

Tags: iphone, components, uipickerview

How can i disable UIPickerView column?

I want to disable only one column of picker. Lets say i have picker with 3 column and i want to disable second column.

Comment: Mouse? I think you need to take the time to properly explain your problem in more detail, as it doesn't make a lot of sense at the moment.

Comment: will you please elaborate..you wanna dissable interaction from whole picker seletion or only one column

Comment: I want to disable only one column of picker. Lets say i have picker with 3 column and i want to disable second column.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options here.

1) Capture interaction with the second column and override it.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

This method can be implemented to simply go back to where it was before the selection. However, they will still be able to interact with the second column.

2) Simply remove the column from the picker.

I believe this is the best option.  Have some boolean 'showSecondColumn'.  Then, in:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

you can simply check your little flag and return the appropriate number.  UIPickerView has a method: `reloadAllComponents`

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, the best solution is to remove that column. But in my case all columns must be visible and some columns' user interaction must be disabled(must not wheel), and also visually must be as disabled. Thanks, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to disable column. I solved(not best solution) like this:

1. get column as "image" (snapshot)
2. grayscale "image"
3. set "image view" user interaction enabled
4. add "image view" to picker as subview

If there is any better way it would be great.